# How to show the data properly in the table

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, html-table

I have PHP code which reads a JSON field value and displayed in the table format my code is working fine but the data is not arranged properly.

```php
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$dataproducts = get_field( "data_product", $post_id);
$data = json_decode($dataproducts);
$table = '
<table class="company-sub-table">
<colgroup>
<col>
<col>
<col>
<col>
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Uses Data Product</th>
    <th>Customer Type</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
';
foreach ($data as $dataproducts_var) {
  foreach ($dataproducts_var->name as $name_of_dp)
  {
 
  echo "<script>console.log('Console: " . $name_of_dp . "' );</script>";
    $name_dp = $name_of_dp;
  echo "<script>console.log('Console: " . $name_dp . "' );</script>";
    $table .= '
        <tr>
            <td>' . $name_dp . '</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
    
    foreach ($dataproducts_var->description as $description)
    {
        $description_to_print = $description;
        $table .= '
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>' . $description_to_print . '</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            ';
    }
    foreach ($dataproducts_var->uses_data_product as $uses_dp)
    {
        $uses_dp_to_display = $uses_dp;
        $table .= '
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>' . $uses_dp_to_display  . '</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            ';
    }
    foreach ($dataproducts_var->customer_type as $c_type)
    {
        $c_type_to_display = $c_type;
        $table .= '
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>' . $c_type_to_display . '</td>
            </tr>
            ';
    }
}
$table .= '
    </tbody>
</table>
';
echo $table;
```

[image: this is the table looks like]

this is the json field value

```
[{"name":["JDLink "],"description":["Solution that fits any make/model of equipment, including older John Deere and non-John Deere equipment. Places essential machine information such as location, machine hours, and alerts at the usersu2019 fingertips, leaving them in complete control to increase machine productivity."],"uses_data_product":["GPS Data, Equipment/Maintanence Data"],"customer_type":["Vehicle Fleet Operators"]},{"name":["Granular Insights"],"description":["John Deere's telematics system supports operational improvements by providing information such as field ops data like hours, acres and quantities of inputs applied, and crops harvested. Premium services are sold at 6$ per Acre. "],"uses_data_product":["Farm Yeild Data"],"customer_type":["Farmers"]}]
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: @OrisSin done please check now

Comment: you highlighted in red some empty cells like if you were surprised. But in your foreach loops you are crafting <tr> table rows containing each time only one populated cell. So it seems it works as expected. Did you instead wanted to render those rows with values all in the same line?

Comment: @DiegoDeVita yes i wants to render the values all in the same line

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly got your problem, you just needed to render those values in the same line. So I grouped all your foreach loops in a single one that is looping through the first array $dataproducts_var->name. The loop will also use a counter that will keep track of the current index in that array that will be used to access to the values belonging to same tuple from the other arrays:

```
    /**
     * Loops through the items in the array $dataproducts_var->name
     *
     * The foreach statement includes the $loopIndex var, that will be
     * needed to reach the values from the other arrays belonging to same row
     */
    foreach ($dataproducts_var->name as $loopIndex => $name_of_dp)

        /**
         *   Collects data, to show in the table row,
         *   from the other arrays in the $dataproducts_var object
         *   using the $loopIndex counter
         * 
         *   The routines expects those arrays to have all the same size and their
         *   values to be at the same position if they belong to the same row here
         */
        $description_to_print =  $dataproducts_var->description[$loopIndex];    
        $uses_dp_to_display = $dataproducts_var->uses_data_product[$loopIndex];
        $c_type_to_display = $dataproducts_var->customer_type[$loopIndex];    

        $table .= '
            <tr>
                <td>' . $name_of_dp . '</td>
                <td>' . $description_to_print . '</td>
                <td>' . $uses_dp_to_display . '</td>
                <td>' . $c_type_to_display . '</td>
            </tr>
            ';
    }
```

Comment: thanks it is showing the data properly now

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful. if it correctly fulfilled your request I hope you'll accept my answer as valid :)